# Adding rows to matlab table

Tags: matlab

I have a table named `patients` in matlab that I created from reading an excel file using the `readtable` command. Now I would like to add a new row to this table programmatically. I have attempted the following:

```
patients.LastName{end+1} = 'Stewart';
```

While this does add a value at the correct spot in the table, it gives a generic name to my row. My `RowNames` property in this instance is important.

How do I add a new row to my table in Matlab and give it a name, then populate it's contents?

Answer (score 0):

This is because all other entries except Last Name are empty. But no worries. In order to assign specific Rownames, please use the following statement. Lets suppose you want to assign last names as row names of the table.

```
patients.Properties.RowNames = patients.LastName;
```